# How do you regex an address pattern?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to match pattern in regex for address. For example, 456-123 Wall St. I want to set regex pattern similar to the this with (-123) could be optional and the last bit of the string must be an alphabet.

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
bool(re.match(r'^(\d)[-]?(\d)?\s[a-zA-Z]+$','123-123 fs'))
```

Comment: Before engaging in this task, I *highly* recommend reading over [falsehoods programmers believe about addresses](https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood#postal-addresses), especially the note about ["why regular expressions and street addresses do not mix"](https://smartystreets.com/articles/regular-expressions-for-street-addresses).

Answer (score 1):

I used https://regex101.com/ to try and match your example address. Is this what you were looking for?

```
^(\d+)([-]?)(\d+)(\s?)([a-zA-Z]+)(\s?)([a-zA-Z]+)$
```

If you want to include the period after St., you can use

```
^(\d+)([-]?)(\d+)(\s?)([a-zA-Z]+)(\s?)([a-zA-Z]+)(\.?)$
```